# What to do with the mental-health tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We kind-of discussed this in a [related post](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1588/4140).

We recently got two questions tagged [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health):

- [How to overcome these learning difficulties and progress in academia?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/46936/4140)
- [“Anonymous” is so distressed that he is having trouble functioning [duplicate]](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/46032/4140)

Then again, [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) [explicitly covers "cognitive, mental, sensory, emotional, or developmental" impairments](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/disability/info). So [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health) seems to be a proper subset of [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability).

---

Then *yet* again, most of the [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) questions really could be retagged [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health). Explicitly, I'd argue that out of 20 [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) questions, *all but the following* could be tagged [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health):

- [Does disability impact on prospects of employment in academia?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2901/4140)
- [Dismissed by my committee](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2808/4140)
- [Disclosing hidden disability to employer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/43062/4140)
- [How does Stephen Hawking conduct his research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/41576/4140)

(Yes, I'm putting speech impairments under the "mental" category here, since they usually involve language centers in the brain, unless there is some trauma to the vocal apparatus. Clinical psychologists, neurologists etc. are welcome to correct me.)

---

I see a couple of ways to proceed here.

- **Clearly separate physical and mental disabilities**, by tagging the 4 questions above [physical-disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-disability), retagging the other 16 [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) questions [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health), black-listing the [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) tag, and adding [mental-disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-disability) as a synonym for [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health) (so people find it when they type "disability" into the tag box).
- **Merge the two concepts**, by retagging the [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health) questions to [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) and blacklisting [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health).
- **Do nothing**, and let nature take its course.

---

Given that I see three alternatives, the usual upvote=yes, downvote=no meta mechanism won't be useful here. So I'll create three answers corresponding to the three alternatives. Please vote your preference, and comment as appropriate.

Comment: I don't really like the idea of blacklisting "mental health" as a tag. I believe this does more to **stigmatize** such issues than to help them be discussed openly. We need to be aware of such problems, and help people suffering from them, not force them to hide it to continue their studies or professions.

Comment: Given the current vote count (4 for merging mental-health with health-issues, 2 for do nothing) I have merged mental-health with health-issues.

Answer (score 7):

I think [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health) should be merged with [health-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-issues).

I'm reposting here a highly-upvoted [comment](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/is-the-seemingly-high-prevalence-of-clinical-depression-cases-in-a-se-askers-nor#comment7196_1592) on a related meta question:

> I am very much against a mental-health tag, just because I am concerned about contributing to the misconception that mental health issues are somehow not "real" medical issues.

See related discussion there.

Comment: We can define [tag:mental-health] as a synonym for [tag:health-issues] or of [tag:disability] (how do *these* two tags relate?). However, it really isn't. [tag:mental-health] is a *proper* subset of each of those others. Does this make a difference?

Comment: @Stephan My point was that I *don't* think we should separately categorize the subset, because I fear it gives a wrong impression.

Comment: @Stephan As for [tag:disability], personally I think it should be a synonym of [tag:health-issues]... but that's another discussion.

Comment: [Mens sana in corpore sano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mens_sana_in_corpore_sano), and also its various inverses.  I think the issues are really inextricable, so far as site like this goes. Let us merge by aliasing mental-health to health-issues.

Answer (score 3):

**Do nothing**, and let nature take its course.

Comment: Not all disabilities are physical and not all mental health issues are disabilities. The idea of merging them seems wrong and the proposed separation seems too fine grained to me. I see no problem with questions having both tags. If the tags are not consistently being used incorrectly, I see no problem.

Comment: Someone who is color blind has a disability, but may or may not have mental health problems.  Similarly with speech-language, hearing, vision, mobility, etc.  Leaving multiple tags for people to choose from allows people to self-identify as they see fit.  The person with the health issue himself should have the freedom to choose the tags that he feels fit the best.

Answer (score -2):

**Clearly separate physical and mental disabilities**, by tagging the 4 questions above [physical-disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-disability), retagging the other 16 [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) questions [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health), black-listing the [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) tag, and adding [mental-disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-disability) as a synonym for [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health) (so people find it when they type "disability" into the tag box).

Answer (score -2):

**Merge the two concepts**, by retagging the [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health) questions to [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) and blacklisting [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health).