# Please undo the synonymisation of the tag disability with health-issues

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag **[disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability)** is currently synonymised with [health-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-issues) (see the [full list of synonyms for `health-issues`](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/health-issues/synonyms)). Based on the [list of tag synonyms](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), this synonym was created on 22 June 2019, so it doesn't look like this was a direct consequence of [What to do with the mental-health tag](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1783/62311) from June 2015.

Both the tag synonymisation and some of the proposals in the June 2015 question appear to be based on a model of disability that treats disability as (1) primarily a medical issue and (2) a problem that belongs to the individual. In my area of work—digital accessibility—and in [disability studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disability_studies) this is known as the [**medical model of disability**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_model_of_disability). Based on the medical model, disability requires a "cure" or, if that is not feasible, adjustment or behavioural change in the individual as a surrogate "cure".

This model is now outdated and has been replaced with the [**social model of disability**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_model_of_disability), which does not deny the impact of the impairment but does not seek to change the person either. According to the social model, "disability" refers "to the restrictions caused by society when it does not give equivalent attention and accommodation to the needs of individuals with impairments" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_model_of_disability)), to " the result of the interaction between people living with impairments and an environment filled with physical, attitudinal, communication and social barriers" ([People with Disability Australia](https://pwd.org.au/resources/disability-info/social-model-of-disability/)) or to "a socially created problem and a matter of the full integration of individuals into society" ([Disabled World](https://www.disabled-world.com/definitions/disability-models.php)).
(The medical and the social models are by no means the two only models of disability, but I hope that we can handle this tagging question without additional disability theory.)

What I am asking by requesting to undo the synonymisation between [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) and [health-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-issues) is for Academia SE to leave behind the outdated medical model of disability. (I do not wish to imply that Academia SE defends or promotes the medical model, only that is seems to be implicit in these tag synonyms.)

This would mean that, for example, the following questions would no longer be tagged [health-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-issues) but [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability):

- [How do conferences work for deaf scientists?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/154710/62311)
- [Teaching visual tools for visually impaired students?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/153531/62311)
- [Does the Americans With Disabilities Act require accommodations for students whose disability prevents them from behaving ethically?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/153447/62311) (currently closed)
- [How should I apply for readmission to a graduate program from which I had to withdraw due to misconduct caused by a disability?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/152114/62311)
- (probably) [Trying to volunteer as a research assistant post-Master's and not having any success so far](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/150007/62311) (currently closed)
- [Oral Defense for Hearing Impaired Student](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145404/62311)

(This list is not intended to be exhaustive. There are a number of questions that are still tagged [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) even though they were submitted after 22 June 2019, e.g. [Does FERPA require parental notification of disability assessment?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/135519/62311) .)

Desynonymising [disability](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability) is not a *perfect* solution. Strictly speaking, some of the above question would be more appropriately tagged [accessibility](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility), but that tag does not exist on this site and creating it *might* be harder to achieve here.

---

**Update 05.09.2020**: On second thought, [inclusion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inclusion) or [disability-inclusion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability-inclusion) (the latter is a term used by the [CDC in the USA](https://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/disabilityandhealth/disability-inclusion.html)) may be a better tag than [accessibility](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility). It would definitely work well for questions such as [How do conferences work for deaf scientists?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/154710/62311), [Teaching visual tools for visually impaired students?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/153531/62311) and [Oral Defense for Hearing Impaired Student](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145404/62311).

Comment: I like moving to "accessibility" anyway ... would synonymizing both to that still be problematic? I confess I'm not understanding the nuance here completely after a couple of reads. But thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim `accessibility` would be the best fit for questions such as "How do conferences work for deaf scientists?", "Teaching visual tools for visually impaired students?" and "Oral Defense for Hearing Impaired Student"; these questions are about integrating persons with specific impairments, not about the impairments as such. Synonymizing `accessibility`with `disability` would be less objectionable than the current situation.

Comment: Well, yes, since questions about the impairments themselves would off-topic, no?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Which seems to support the argument that `disability` is a poor choice for a tag name...

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but it's not that important, I don't think.

Comment: Oh that's why my changing that tag kept reverting for no apparent reason.  Yes, this is a terrible synonym.

Comment: I do not think `inclusion` is a good tag for this application. It's too vague - is it about including first-generation students, is it about including women in a men-dominated field? It suggests to me "making people feel welcome" which is not the same as "how to help people physical access X."

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Actually, "How to help people with physical access" is basically, "How to not exclude people through physical access barriers" in disguise. And the issues you mention are, in fact, all related.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Okay, sure, but someone who is an expert in building inclusive learning environments is not an expert in helping someone with physical or mental disabilities navigate the university system. So when thinking of the tag as "helping experts find questions they can answer," I don't think it's as good as it *could be*.

Comment: It's like how we have [sexual-misconduct] and [personal-misconduct] instead of just [misconduct]

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim I see your point about `inclusion`, so I have added `disability-inclusion` as an alternative.

Comment: @Tsundoku Works for me. I would suggest though, that as a meta question, you make your suggested tags answers so we can vote on them; right now it's not clear what a vote up on this question means, does it mean "this is a valid concern," "`accessiblity` is a good tag," or "`disability-inclusion` is a good tag."

Comment: Coming from a US perspective, the "Americans with Disabilities Act" is a quite central piece of legislation that adds the "disability" label to a lot of things. I'm sympathetic to reframing the way we talk about disability, but it remains true that at US universities you will probably encounter the "disability office" rather than the "accessibility office" or "inclusion office" (and the latter is more likely to refer to racial inclusion, non-native English speakers, religious minorities, etc).

Comment: Forgive my, perhaps, overgeneralizing, but ... It seems there may be a fair amount of common ground between those who are discriminated against (for race, creed, color, religion, sex, gender, disability) -- all because they are different from some perceived "norm".  While each area has different challenges, all exist because of some perceived 'norm' and the lack of acceptance or discrimination against (conscious or unconscious) of those who don't fit people's mental model of "normal". 

A question: what is more normal: having such biases or not?  Can a society be cohesive if it has no norms?

Comment: @BryanKrause I have suggested the term `disability-inclusion` in a separate answer. I prefer it over `accessibility`  in spite my awareness of the ADA, because accessiblity usually refers to "to the design of products, devices, services, or environments so as to be usable by people with disabilities", i.e. technical aspects, whereas questions related to disability inclusion on Academia SE focus on social aspects rather than strictly technical ones.

Comment: @Astara Those are valid concerns, but this question is about getting rid of the medical bias with regard to disability, not about discrimination in general. Academia SE already has tags for [tag:ethnicity] (synonymised with [tag:race]) and [tag:discrimination].

Comment: As someone with a disability, I find the social model of disability incredibly patronising and dehumanising. My disability is very much a health issue, and I'm desperate for a cure. To suggest that my disability is not a health issue and is a socially-created condition is extremely insulting and complete BS on so many levels. YMMV

Comment: @BobsaysreinstateMonica I believe the idea here is to allow a distinction to be made between disability and more general health-related questions, rather than to impose it.  Users would be free to use both tags at once.

Answer (score 7):

While I do see the problem here, I think that having two separate tags does not really solve it while creating more problems:

- By the nature of our site, we almost exclusively focus on the social aspect anyway. For the questions we get, it mostly does not matter whether something is a disability or a health issue (wherever one draws the line between the two). To give a somewhat unrealistic, but illustrative example, whether somebody cannot access a lecture hall because of a broken leg or a permanent paralysis hardly affects our approach to the problem. Indeed, sometimes the answer to a question is that some health issue qualifies as a disability and thus grants certain rights.
- The line between a permanent disability and temporary health issue is indisputably blurry, or one might say that one thing can be a disability or a health issue depending whether you view it from a social or medical point of view (which is not so different from your outline).
- Again by the nature of our site, most questions in [health-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-issues) are about disabilities or something that may be one. In fact, in a brief search I couldn’t even find a single question which I would consider correctly tagged [health-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-issues), but which was clearly not about disabilities.

As a consequence, I expect that splitting the tag as proposed would lead to users being confused as to which tag they should use and users not finding existing questions that help them. If we ignore everything related to the name of the tag for a second, what do we gain from splitting?

Instead, I suggest that we think about a better name for the main tag (i.e., the synonym target). This is obviously not an easy choice as one has to consider amongst others:

- Some choices may cause people refraining from using the tag altogether due to social stigma, e.g., [disabilities](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disabilities).
- Some choices may cause the undesirable associations you describe, e.g., [health-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-issues). (Though I am somewhat surprised by that since at least to me *health issue* does not imply that something requires cure or similar – not that I dispute that others have this association.)

Here, I would like to play the ball back to you, the expert. But even if there should be no good and concise name for this, I would refrain from splitting the tag. In that case, I would consider even a super-clunky name like [accomodating-and-handling-health-issues-and-disabilities](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accomodating-and-handling-health-issues-and-disabilities) the lesser evil.

Comment: [{physical,mental}-{accommodations,accessibility}]?

Comment: I prefer the asker's proposal.  Not having the tag seems the most stigmatizing thing.  If it's both a disability and a health issue, both tags can be used.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: *If it's both a disability and a health issue, both tags can be used.* – Then where would you draw the line between the two and how can we ensure that users draw it and we do not end up with a lot of badly tagged questions? Are there any questions where one of the two tags clearly does not apply? After all, all disabilities are related to health issues, even if though I see the point that viewing them from this angle is undesirable.

Comment: "a lot of badly tagged questions?"  I don't think that's a real problem that needs solving.

Comment: "Are there any questions where one of the two tags clearly does not apply? After all, all disabilities are related to health issues,"  Tsundoku gave a very clear explanation for why that attitude is not appropriate for this site.  You should follow Tsundoku's advice.  It's trivial to make a question about health issues that is not about disability; maybe "How does sick leave for for graduate students?"

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: *"a lot of badly tagged questions?" I don't think that's a real problem that needs solving* – How is this not a problem? Tags exist for finding content and similar. If badly tagged questions do not concern you, why not just delete all the tags in question? — *Tsundoku gave a very clear explanation for why that attitude is not appropriate for this site.* – Tsundoku’s argument is that we should not primarily focus on disabilities as a health issue that can be cured or similar, which I do not object to. However, that does not mean that disabilities are not related to health.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: *It's trivial to make a question about health issues that is not about disability; maybe "How does sick leave for for graduate students?"* – Sure, but that’s not my point. My point is that we rarely or never get such questions.

Comment: I'd have no problem with eliminating tags entirely.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist The fact that you'd eliminate tags entirely, doesn't mean that others wouldn't find them useful.

Comment: `accomodating-and-handling-health-issues-and-disabilities`? I'd rather not lump disability/impairment together with health issues. For questions about how to integrate students or researchers with a disability, [tag:inclusion] sounds like a better option.

Comment: @Tsundoku: I like [tag:inclusion] as well. I will try to go through some questions in the tag systematically to see whether this fits everything or whether some other major subcategories come up (which then may get their own tag or give us some insight on how to proceed).

Comment: Is there a problem with using the tag `accessiblity`? AFAIK that's the standard term for this kind of thing, for example your phone has a menu called 'accessibility settings'.

Comment: @BrtH: Well, to begin with it is not what is typically used for accomodation of psychiatric disabilities, which make up a considerable amount of what’s in the tag. Unfortunately, I couldn’t do the thorough assessment of the tag I wanted to do yet, so I cannot be any more detailed on this.

Comment: @BrtH "accessibility" is less standard outside the US, in my experience.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I am outside the US. '[Toegankelijkheid](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=nl&tl=en&text=Toegankelijkheid)' is the standard term in Dutch. However, it's not that I have a very strong opinion about this, I was more wondering why people are making it so difficult for themselves if a standard term already exists.

Comment: @BrtH As I explained in another comment on this page, accessibility / toegankelijkheid refers to the technical aspect (digital accessibility, building accessibility, etc), whereas the tag we are looking for should primarily cover the social aspects.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Note that we already have an [tag:inclusivity] tag. It's currently used on four questions (of which all but one are also tagged with [tag:diversity], and the last one probably should be, too). If an [tag:inclusion] tag is added, [tag:inclusivity] should definitely be a synonym (or the questions should just be retagged).

Comment: Also, regarding the potentially narrow scope of [tag:health-issues] if disability questions are removed from it, how about renaming it to just [tag:health] to broaden the scope a little? (We already have [tag:healthcare] as a synonym of it anyway, so it's clearly not _just_ about specific health issues.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Three out of the four [tag:inclusvity] questions are irrelevant to [tag:disability-inclusion] since they are about gender diversity or (the closed one) race. Only the [last one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/139141/62311) may be relevant to [tag:disability-inclusion].

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: *how about renaming it to just health to broaden the scope a little?* – I concur. Also see my first answer.

Answer (score 6):

To have some data to help deciding, I went through a bunch of questions in the current that [heath-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heath-issues). I excluded only closed questions. I categorised the questions along three axes:

- Mental (depression, ADHD, etc.) vs. physical (broken leg, cancer, blindness, etc.):

  - 28 questions were about mental issues.
  - 6 questions were about physical issues.
  - 4 questions did not specify anything.

  I want to mention that I think the distinction does not affect the answer for many of these questions, even when accounting for the stigma of mental issues. (Though I did not do a statistics on that.)
- Disabilities and chronic diseases vs. short-term issues. I went for the former when in doubt, which mostly applied to mental-health issues.

  - 28 questions were about disabilities or chronic diseases.
  - 3 questions were clearly not about disabilities.
  - 5 questions were about preventing health problems, mostly psychohygiene.
  - For 2 questions it was completely unclear.
- Accommodation and handling bad performances vs. other issues.

  - 21 questions were about accommodation and handling bad performance.
  - 12 questions were clearly about something else (including the 5 questions about preventing health problems).
  - 5 questions were not clear about this on account of broadness (“How do you handle …?”).

Answer (score 3):

Since `Azor Ahai -- he him` [suggested](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/please-undo-the-synonymisation-of-the-tag-disability-with-health-issues#comment14730_4783) that I should post an alternative tag as an answer, here is a suggestion: introduce the tag [disability-inclusion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disability-inclusion) for (suggested tag wiki excerpt)

> Questions about the inclusion of people with disabilities in higher education. These questions can cover both social practices and technological challenges, and can apply to either students or teaching staff.

This should be broad enough to cover all the examples listed in my question above.

Comment: *This should be broad enough to cover all the examples listed in my question above.* – And what do we do with the rest of questions in that tag? Does this tag fit? If not, what does fit and is splitting along this line a good idea?

Comment: Maybe add another tag, [qualified-disability] for people who have received certification from the disability office? So a prof might ask about [disability-inclusion] when preparing colorblind slides, but a student could ask about boht.

Comment: @AzorAhai: *Maybe add another tag, [qualified-disability] for people who have received certification from the disability office?* – This sounds like a horrible line to draw: “Your disability is not qualified; you must not use this tag.” Moreover, this distinction is irrelevant for a considerable amount of questions.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft True, it does have a bad ring.