# Questions related to ADHD among students and academics

Tags: discussion, tags, on-topic-ness

Should questions that focus on the effects of ADHD on academics and students be on or off topic? For example: [Survive the postdoc stage having ADHD](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/177484/75368).

And the OP has added a new tag. I'm of mixed feelings about whether to expand the wiki or delete the tag [adhd](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adhd). Advice?

Technically it is a medical issue, but a lot of folks in academia are affected by it.

Comment: I am not sure that asking for specific types of productivity advice should be considered a medical issue. Even if it were the case, I don't think there is anything wrong in discussing questions related to performance (excluding medication), when these questions are related to someone's physical/mental/neurological condition. Prohibiting it just leads to exclusion of such people. There are questions from blind people on this website, they are not banned, why ADHD should be?

Comment: regarding the tag I have no strong opinion

Comment: My worry is that some advice might conflict with medical advice, thus I asked for guidance. I can do the wiki if we keep  the tag.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Of course if random people would start suggesting undergrads tacking stimulants every time they struggle at an exam, that would not be good. But productivity advice cannot possibly do any harm, I think. ADHD is an under-researched field in general and many of the productivity advice doctors give themselves are not very much evidence-based medicine anyway.

Comment: Similar questions: https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=adhd+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano. Most of them use the [health] or [disability] tag, however (if at all).

Comment: @GoodDeeds, yes, I made a search before posting this. It has come up several times. If it is "on topic" then the tag is probably warranted.

Comment: Ignoring the question of on-topicness for a moment, why not use the [health] tag for such questions, if on-topic? (Also, I think this is slightly relevant: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/please-undo-the-synonymisation-of-the-tag-disability-with-health-issues)

Comment: @GoodDeeds, I won't express an opinion on it. I'm vigilant about new tags without wiki provided and have removed quite a few of them. Added wiki to a few others. Just looking for advice here, but don't have a position. This case seemed different to me so I didn't act on my own.

Comment: RE the tag, I think adding an "ADHD" tag would invite the creation of other tags for autism, depression, imposter-syndrome, etc. Better to have a catch-all tag [tag:mental-health]...which we already have (it's a synonym of [tag:health], for better or for worse, but it exists). So, I recommend using the (mental) health tag instead of creating this new tag.

Comment: @cag51, I've replaced the tag for the moment. So [tag:adhd] is now an orphan. But that still leaves the question about whether such things are "on topic".

Comment: @buffy - awesome, thanks. Agree that I didn't answer the title question (that's why I only wrote a comment); let us see what others say.

Answer (score 12):

I recommend keeping these questions. School is not designed for (and often hostile to) people with ADHD, thus [many underachieve](https://chadd.org/about-adhd/long-term-outcomes/) and do not make it to higher levels of academia. Therefore, most academic advice out there on the internet for people with ADHD tends to be geared towards children, high school students, or college freshman. This is one of the only places I can think of that could host advice for ADHD folks trying to do serious academic work. There are a lot of novel problems that come with that which are inherently on topic.

I'd also like to push back on merging the tag with [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health), because the experience of ADHD is very different from things like depression or imposter syndrome or burnout. It really doesn't belong with those-- and while we're at it, neither does autism. It would be more appropriate to create a [neurodivergence](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neurodivergence) tag for these, if you must have an umbrella. These are not health problems, and there are many who would be fairly cheesed to see them considered as such.

Comment: A [neurodivergence] tag seems like a great idea.

Comment: Many would also happily agree that their ADHD or autism cause interference in daily living, which is the DSM criterion. I don't want to get too far into that argument, but I would support the idea of separating them out from [tag:mental-health] for the reasons you describe. I'm not sure an umbrella tag is necessary.

Comment: For many of these mental health issues, a canonical answer would always be "See a health care professional". Imposter syndrome is probably different. neurodivergence is unlikely to ever be noticed by anyone. Normally the questions are about individual response, not how to build a better academic system.

Comment: A neurodivergence tag would be quite likely to be noticed by the neurodivergent, as well as those interested in building an academic system that is more inclusive with respect to neurodiversity. (I do think individual tags would be better, and support their existence for the same reasons.) Regarding the individualized nature of the questions you've seen so far, I would expect better questions to appear once it is clear that they are welcome here and will not simply be dismissed (e.g. "see a health care professional") or lead to further stigmatization.

Comment: I think you make a great point that we are one of the few places that can host advice for neurodivergent folks doing serious academic work. But, I worry that none of us are really qualified to be giving advice. Even if someone has (say) ADHD or a close family member with ADHD, it is difficult to say that they should be giving advice to others, in whom the presentation may be quite different. And only a tiny subset of our community will have any real familiarity with these types of questions -- though others may try to give well-intentioned, common-sense advice, which is not helpful.

Comment: RE the tags -- one option (though it's a major change) would be to separate [tag:health] from [tag:mental-health]. Perhaps we could  then make [tag:neurodivergence] a synonym of [tag:mental-health] (or vice versa). I understand your point that they are not exactly synonyms, but that doesn't mean we need separate tags for them (and hoping that users will understand the subtle distinctions between our tags when they tag their question is a losing battle).

Comment: @cag51 Relevant: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1787/68109

Comment: Yupp, that is the historical reason, but no reason we can't revisit six years later.

Comment: I agree that medical advice about adhd would be off-topic here-- let me challenge the frame. I have in mind questions like "Will my academic reputation suffer if I use a double time accommodation on my quals?" or "Which countries can I not do a post-doc in as an individual on Adderall?" or "What to do when I inevitably forget to go to classes that I am teaching?" These are not so much questions about ADHD as they are *questions about operating in academia* in which ADHD is already a given. In particular, they require the expertise of those working in academia, rather than medical expertise.

Comment: Ah -- yeah, those example questions are on topic for sure. But in those examples, the details of the underlying health condition seem almost irrelevant, which sort of argues against the need for any tag more specific than (mental) health, no?

Comment: I'd argue all of those are primarily of interest to people with ADHD, and a tag would help them find them better. I could make the questions more explicitly about ADHD, though-- just from the top of my head, "Avoiding ADHD stigma as a grad student" or "Will it reduce my authority to tell my students I have ADHD so they don't interrupt and derail me during lecture?" or "My PI doesn't believe in ADHD and wants me to resist giving students accommodations"

Comment: Stop treating health problems as something to be shamed of. Everyone can have health problems, a lot of thing *are* health problems. ADHD is a chronic mental disorder, and as such must be treated according to the professional guidelines.

What you are proposing is something along the lines "a woman with painful menstruation has not an health issue, so she can perform her job without hindrances and if she claim so, she has no right". What do you propose then? that she hardens up and ignores the pain? Please explain it to me

Comment: @EarlGrey The language here matters. Does predisposition to painful menstruation mean that being a woman is a health problem? You wouldn't say that women are afflicted with Female Gender Disorder. And yet neurodivergent people are labeled-- by the neurotypical, mind you-- as disordered or mentally unhealthy, despite their neurodivergence being just as determined from birth, just as "incurable", and just as essential to their identity as being female. It is part of *who they are*, and despite the difficulties that may come with it, it is not a *problem*.

Comment: We are not anymore in the 60s. Determining someone has health problem(s), is not anymore related to putting someone in an asylum. But I understand your premises as well your defensive attitudes, however I see no common ground to further the discussion. The need of defining neurodivergent vs neurotypical (what is typical? please define it) is just the supposed-to-be-good side of a fascist attitude toward society, where there are the "normal" people and there are the "different" people. I personally think there are only "different" people, no reason to further divide people.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber First of all - I'm in psychology and I think getting the phrasing right is very important. In search of finding the right phrasing, what is the difference between "something that comes with difficulties" and a "problem"?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- A "problem" to me implies that it is undesirable and one ought to be seeking to solve it. ADHD comes with certain challenges, like forgetfulness, and while someone with ADHD may develop ways to compensate, it's also possible to accept that one's brain works differently and that that is okay. Referring to disabilities as "problems" (even as "disorders", arguably) puts the onus on the individual to correct themselves and become "normal." But I think that it is up to society to be inclusive-- to provide an environment which accommodates their needs (the difficulties) without

Comment: So you delineate ADHD as being something you're born with and hence it (1) can't be cured; (2) is essential to identity; and (3) is therefore not a health problem. Is that distinction also useful for physical disabilities? We can contrast a broken leg and having Crohn's. Crohn's comes with difficulties, after all. I also wonder about using neurodivergence implying thresholds for users. Does a question tagged "neurodivergence" need a diagnosis? Obviously everything is a spectrum, but where can we helpfully create tags for "I have trouble listening for two hours" and "I have an ADHD dx"?

Comment: ...implying that there is something wrong with them. We build ramps for people in wheelchairs, provide interpreters for the deaf, but judge people with ADHD as irresponsible when they have trouble making deadlines or remembering appointments. It's implied that the ADHD itself is a problem, one that could be solved if the person would just stop being like that, and at the very least that they must seek medical help to fit into society's expectations.

Comment: I don't know enough about Crohn's to comment on that specific example, but I do think the distinction is useful for physical disabilities. Regarding a diagnosis, I mean, I don't think we have to show proof of enrollment to post in [tag:graduate-school], it's just for questions related to graduate school. A neurodivergence tag would be for questions related to neurodivergence. Or, if your question is whether in general one has to be diagnosed to be neurodivergent, the lines are fuzzy. The wikipedia for neurodiversity or the autism rights movement could point you to some good discussions.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber No, I know. I didn't mean to suggest you had to have a dx to post in [tag:adhd], I meant I think we *should* have tags for people who need help with their diagnosed ADHD and people that struggle with attention sometimes (who doesn't?), and they may be off-put by using a tag [tag:adhd]. After all, an "expert" in ADHD probably isn't much help with someone dealing with subclinical att. problems, and neither is an "expert" in sublinical att. an "expert" in real ADHD. See my terminology suggestion below.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber ADD/ADHD is a catch-all term used by doctors for a wide range of issues that impact one's mental state.  The principal cause for it is often unrecognized by doctors: neurotoxins.  Lead, mercury, bismuth, arsenic, etc. impact the nervous system considerably and can be difficult to remove.  A person can be born with these toxins, but the ADHD is not a _genetic_ condition per se.  Chelation therapy can remove them, but it is often the case that they get purged from the body over time and people tend to outgrow the condition, which is why more focus is on younger people with it.

Comment: @Polyhat While I understand there is some observed correlation between lead exposure and ADHD, I find it highly disingenuous to characterize this as the "principal cause." It is also not a "catch all term," there are very specific diagnostic criteria (though I will agree that the condition is not as well-understood as I would like it to be). You sound like you have been exposed to some misinformation on this topic. I would encourage you to look into the resources at chadd.org for more reliable research.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber My father is a physician who specializes in toxicology.  I helped him with some original research on thousands of his patient records comparing hair-mineral analysis (HMA) results to patient diagnoses.  We saw very clear connections/correlations.  The results of our study, however, have never been published, so I can understand why you, and others, might not see any connection.  We have seen people cured of the condition through detoxification therapies.

Comment: You will forgive me if I harbor doubts about your secret research study. I suggest that you expose it to peer review before making claims about causes or cures of conditions for which there is already an extensive body of literature.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber It remains unpublished, not for any surreptitiousness on our part, but simply for the fact that the doctor is too busy to take time to write it all up and figure out how to publish it.  He is a doctor, not a researcher nor author.  To be honest, this analysis was done over twenty years ago when toxicology was in its infancy.  As for your doubts--feel free.  It is proper to question unverified internet reports.  But keep an open mind, and watch for the cause/effect relationship of toxins to ADHD going forward.

Comment: @Polyhat In medicine, "I've done a study that shows XYZ but I haven't gotten around to publishing it yet" is the academic equivalent of perpetual motion cranks and trisectors. If a physician really had data in their possession that could improve treatment for millions and failed to share it, they're doing the world a great disservice. More likely, there are substantial problems with the work, like with most individual research endeavors, and it would not stand to scrutiny. An unprinted study isn't worth the paper it isn't printed on.

Comment: @BryanKrause I can understand your view, but will respectfully disagree.  Beyond the time and other considerations I mentioned earlier, there is another very good reason why this study has never been written up and published.  I won't go into details here except to say that it has nothing to do with the truth or the medical/scientific facts, nor even with the manner of presenting them, and everything to do with politics.  That said, it may be possible, after my father retires, to expand and complete the study and publish it.  We'll see.  I would like to see that happen.

Comment: @Polyhat The more you explain, the more it sounds like crankery... A secret study that demonstrated revolutionary results, but isn't being published because of "politics"? Besides, how did your father have the time/resources to do such a study, but not publish it? What was the reason to do the study in the first place if not to publish? This makes no sense.

Comment: @JSLavertu It was never done for any intention to publish. We got the primary HMA data for all the patients from the Doctor's Data laboratory, and we merged it, in an Excel spreadsheet, with our own internal diagnostic records.  I programmed Excel macros by which to mathematically analyze the data and look for correlations. My father wanted to know for his own benefit and that of his patients. He was specifically looking for the compounding effects of having multiple toxins at the same time and how this would affect people. But he wanted evidence linking specific toxins to specific conditions.

Comment: @Polyhat That sounds like a HIPAA nightmare. Regardless, until the research is published and peer reviewed... It's not much more than an empty claim.

Comment: @JSLavertu  I don't remember the exact dates, but it may have been before HIPAA.  I remember when HIPAA came along and I was disgusted by the fact that it required all electronic communications to be done in ASCII..._unencrypted!_ I wasn't impressed.

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest an idea, based on conversations on this page, and also the [function of tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

So let's imagine someone comes to this site looking for help with their (a) chronic illness; or (b) ADHD.

- Separate [health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) from [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health). That never sat very well with me earlier.

  - Let's say person A wants to read about other people's health problems, well half of them are about mental health or ADHD (or similar), that's no use to them, or vice versa.
- Leave [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health) for things like depression, and burnout. I also frankly have no issue creating tags for common mental health problems (they aren't a limited resource). Even if you tag your country, level, [mental-health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health), and the problem, that's four tags.

  - I can see person B perusing this tag to see what else has worked for other people.
- **Suggestion:** To encompass both diagnosed disorders<sup>1</sup> and just general quirks, why don't we try [personal-psychology](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-psychology). Again, I have no issue with creating sub-tags like [adhd](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adhd) as needed, so that someone who has learned to succeed in academia with their ADHD can follow it and be helpful, but not also be bogged down by *every* question in [health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health).

  - This can cover questions like [*Help with becoming overly obsessive (about mathematics)*](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/177046/help-with-becoming-overly-obsessive-about-mathematics), which is currently tagged [health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), which is borderline IMO.
  - But in conjunction with [adhd](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adhd) you could use it on suggested questions *Avoiding ADHD stigma as a grad student*, or *Will it reduce my authority to tell my students I have ADHD so they don't interrupt and derail me during lecture?* or *My PI doesn't believe in ADHD and wants me to resist giving students accommodations* (thanks [Alexander](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4545/alexander-gruber)).
  - No, it wouldn't probably be a big follow target, but it declutters [health](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health).

This avoids the issue with calling certain things "disorders" (which wouldn't be relevant for the above question anyway). This paradigm would also mean we don't have to create a fuzzy tag like [neurodiversity](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neurodiversity) which, if applied to the question above, makes it almost useless as a category when asking questions about how to deal with your own brain.

---

1: I'm going to use it for now because, after all, it is what the "D" in ADHD and ASD stand for. While I concede there is a school of thought (which I support) and that individuals living with these may not consider them disorders, others *do* and so instead of coming down on one side of the debate, let's use a different term.

Comment: You seem to have accidentally posted the same answer twice.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Weird, tahnks for the heads up

Answer (score -3):

Personally, I think that *most* of the questions concerning psychological disorders should be closed as dupes, and pointed to some *good* grand answer on the issue.

The counter to that argument would be that individuals can be helped by being responsive to their special issues.  I'd counter that by saying if that's the case, then the question should be closed as being strongly dependent on individual factors.

Comment: So your answer to anything involving a question on this topic is it's either a duplicate, or too individual. Great! That's the site sorted, now we just have to automate the closing and go home.

Comment: @Nij  I don't quite look at it that way.  Rather, I think three or four GOOD canonical answers in the area, perhaps written by someone with a background in counseling in an academic environment, can help a person who needs help better than they've been served by the hundreds of answers that basically say "seek the help of a professional"

Answer (score -6):

ADHD is defined as a mental illness or a mental disorder, so it should fall under the health category.

Since we are discussing ADHD in relation to the academic life of  a person in his adult age, I would like to add a side consideration (and somehow a darker tone). In the recent past women were declared insane during the menopause. And for this reason they were forced to go to mental institution, as late as in the 60s.

Menopause mental disorder, on the other hand, is now a recognized mental disorder (perimenopausal mental disorders, to be more precise).

Long story short: would you conisder having a menopause tag?

Comment: On the presumption that this is meant in good faith: if MMD was creating enough issues regarding work and life specific to academia, and generating enough questions here about those issues that they formed a considerable proportion of any other potential tag which would identify them separately, all other tags the same, then **yes** of course we'd have that tag, and it would be very questionable why we wouldn't use it if needed.

Comment: @Nij I honestily think that making so many differentiations is pointless and missing the point: it is not important that sickness <x> is relevant, the point is about health questions. Otherwise there is always the smartypantsy guy creeping in "hey, this chronic hemicrania the person is suffering is not a recognized mental disorder, so better the person harden up and get the work done".

Plus: there is no need to disclose the specific health problem, it is enough to state that because of a certain health problem, "productivity" or "worked hours" may be less than equivalent healthy person.

Comment: @EarlGrey Is it though? Chronic depression and ADHD both affect productivity in significant ways but the solutions to either will be completely different. Without that information, the answers might miss the mark completely.

Comment: @JSLavertu Is it though? the answer should be "contact a doctor" in both cases. Any other answer trying to address the medical aspects of these medical conditions without being medical-based answers, (to my mind comes a lot of good faith crap such as "raise your interest in your work" or "calm down and focus") are pure Bach flowers. 
If, on the other hand, the question is "I have a student/PhD/PostDoC suffering from "do not specify condition --> lower productivity " then the informations may be relevant. Unfortunately I still have to see this degree of discussion in Academia, though...

Comment: @EarlGrey I'm going to heavily disagree with that. My doctor doesn't have ADHD or 
 experience with dealing with ADHD in academia. Unless it's an exclusively "medical" issue (which it very rarely is with ADHD), their recommendations are unlikely to go beyond generic tips (exercise, sleep, etc.). From my experience, advice that specifically adresses ADHD from people who either have or deal directly with ADHD has been the most useful, definitively not "pure bach flowers". ADHD affects how one interacts with the world in ways that go far beyond purely medical.

Comment: @EarlGrey To give an analogy, it's like if tags for Python 2 and Python 3 were merged on StackOverflow. Yes, they are both part of the Python programming language, but generic answers that don't take the version into account are unlikely to be useful or optimal. Besides, it's not like tags are in limited supply...

Comment: @JSLavertu I will leave the discussion, because it is strongly hinged on the fact "ADHD is defined as a mental illness or a mental disorder". I am in no way associated with medical studies, so I cannot have an educated opinion. The vast literature of anedoctes I am collecting is that ADHD is not at all a mental illness or a mental disorder, the above mentioned fact seems to me just an assumption. Unfortunately, I do not have the intellectual means to confute medical "science".

Comment: @EarlGrey Fair enough, I'm not too sure about how it should be classified either... Personally, i'd say it's more of a disorder since I didn't "catch" or develop ADHD (as opposed to just having it), but then again, I'm not a medical scientist. So there's that.